# EditorTemplates > bool - bool.cshtml, DateTime? - DateTime?.cshtml (fail)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates

**Without using "UIHint"** how to create .cshtml for certain types of data.

## Examples

### These are already working!

```
[DataType(DataType.Url)]
public string Link { get; set; }
```

will be used

```
Url.cshtml
```

---

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Descrition { get; set; }
```

will be used

```
MultilineText.cshtml
```

### These, I am in doubt about how

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TypesList { get; set; }
```

will be used

```
???????????.cshtml
```

---

```
public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
```

will be used

```
???????????.cshtml
```

---

```
public int? Order { get; set; }
```

will be used

```
???????????.cshtml
```

## Questions

In short, do not want to be putting in my ViewModel attributes, like that would work exactly like "Url" and "Multiline"

What should be the file name `.cshtml` that will be used to `int?`, `IEnumerable<xx>` or `IEnumerable<string>`

```
Remembering that you can not create files with "<", ">" or "?"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By convention (if you don't specify any template name):

- `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TypesList { get; set; }` will use `SelectListItem.cshtml` (not that since you have an `IEnumerable<T>` the editor template will be rendered for each element of the collection and will be called `T.cshtml`)
- `public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }` will use `DateTime.cshtml`
- `public int? Order { get; set; }` will use `Int32.cshtml`
  ...

You could also specify a template name in the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.TypesList, "MyTemplate.cshtml")
```

Assuming `TypesList` is an `IEnumerable<T>` then `MyTemplate.cshtml` will be strongly typed to `IEnumerable<T>` and not to `T`.

Comment: See this..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724295/ienumerable-in-my-viewmodel-is-not-displayed-with-editorformodel

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa, instead of posting another question why didn't you simply update this one and provide more information about what actually you are trying to achieve? Because this particular question here is already answered.

Comment: But doubts are distinct.
They are related but not the same question. 

This question is about how asp.net mvc rendering IEnumerables and  nullables types, since the other is about because it is not rendering IEnumerables

Comment: @RidermandeSousaBarbosa, OK, about this question then: is there something else you would like to know about how ASP.NET MVC is treating `IEnumerable<T>` and nullable type templates in addition to what I already covered?

Comment: You've told me, just got one last question.

How I can create a ".cshtml" specific to `DateTime?` (Nullable only) without using `UIHint`.