# IEnumerable in my ViewModel is not displayed with EditorForModel

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates

## ViewModel

```
[Validator(typeof(ProdutoCategoriaValidator))]
public class ProdutoCategoriaViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Tipos { get; set; }  // <<<<-------  Is not showing in my view

    [AdditionalMetadata("data-bind", "event: { change: function(data) { Link(data.Nome());  }}")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    [AdditionalMetadata("Prefixo", "Produtos/{tipo-de-produto}#")]
    public string Link { get; set; }

    public int? Ordem { get; set; }

    public ProdutoCategoriaViewModel()
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

## Solution

[image: Solution explorer]

## View (_Formulario.cshtml)

```
@model ProdutoCategoriaViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id="form-produtocategoria", data_bind = "submit: salvar" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <legend>@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapTitle()</legend>

    <fieldset>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Verifique os erros abaixo:")
        @Html.EditorForModel()
    </fieldset>

    <div class="buttons">
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancelar", "Index")
        <input type="submit" value="SALVAR" />
    </div>
}
```

## SelectListItem.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, Model)

<p>Test</p>
```

## Result

Full image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K09sg.png

[image: View result]

## Notes

- I've tried to put the attribute "UIHint" but still nothing is displayed!

## Questions

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default when you use `Html.EditorForModel` don't expect this to recurse down to complex properties such as your `Tipos` property which is of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Brad Wilson explained this in his [blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) (more specifically read the **Shallow Dive vs. Deep Dive** section towards the end of the post). You will need to write a custom editor template for the Object type if you want this to happen.

Another possibility is to specify the template name:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Tipos, "SelectListItem")
```

Also bear in mind that your editor template for the `SelectListItem` is wrong because you are binding the DropDownListFor to the model as first argument. Don't forget that the first argument of this helper must be a scalar property that will be used to hold the selected value. You need a string or integer property on your view model for this. The second argument represents the collection.

Another important aspect about editor templates is that when you have a property of type `IEnumerable<T>` and an editor template called `T.cshtml` this editor template must be strongly typed to the `T` class and not `IEnumerable<T>` as you did with your `SelectListItem.cshtml` template. This doesn't apply if you use UIHint or specify the template name as second argument to the EditorFor helper. n this case the template will be typed to the collection.

So to recap, you could either implement a custom object editor template as Brad Wilson suggested that will recurse down to complex properties or you could modify your `_Formulario.cshtml` view to specify EditorFor each individual elements.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. I would not do this for each property, I would make at least using the `UIHint` attribute.  The problem is that even I added `UIHint`, nothing happens!

Comment: @Riderman de Sousa Barbosa, nothing happens because as I said, in the default Object template ASP.NET MVC doesn't recurse down to complex properties. So even if you put an UIHint on your Tipos property it will be ignored. You need to modify the default Object.cshtml template as Brad Wilson showed.

Comment: I got it. Well I wanted to avoid this, but the way I have to do it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Darin, bonus question here: if `T` require `T.cshtml` template name by default then what is the **default** template name for `IEnumerable<T>` without `[UIHint]`? I tried `Ts.cshtml`, a plural name but is not working without `[UIHint]`.

Comment: @CallMeLaNN, the default template for `IEnumerable<T>` is `T.cshtml` which is strongly typed to `T`. ASP.NET MVC will automatically invoke it for each element of the collection.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, sadly, it does not work. I tried already. It does not select template for `IEnumerable<T>` automatically, least I found no one know how to do it automatically. There are only 2 ways currently I ever knew. Pass the template name in the `EditorFor` parameter like `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Ts, "Ts")` or decorate `[UIHint("Ts")]` to the `IEnumerable<T> Ts` property. No choice, at least there is a way.

Comment: @CallMeLaNN, then you must be doing something wrong because this works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

A `@foreach` loop renders something that *looks* right, but the resulting markup will have the same id for each row's controls. It also will not post the enumerable collection back with the model instance.

There are two ways to make this work such that you have a unique id for each item in the collection, and so that the collection is hydrated on postbacks:

**1. Use the default editor template rather than a named one**

```
// editor name parameter must be omitted; default editor template's model type
// should be a single instance of the child object, not an IEnumerable. This 
// convention looks wrong, but it fully works:
@Html.EditorFor(parentObject => parentObject.Items)
```

**2. Use a `@for` loop, not a `@foreach`:**

```
@for (int i = 0; i < parentObject.Items.Count ; i++) {
    // the model binder uses the indexer to disambiguate the collection items' controls: 
    @Html.EditorFor(c => Model.Items[i], "MyEditorTemplate") 
}
```

This will not work, however:

```
// this will error out; the model type will not match the view's at runtime:
@Html.EditorFor(parentObject => parentObject.Items, "MyEditorTemplate")
```

Nor will this:

```
@foreach(var item in parentObject.Items) {
    // this will render, but won't post the collection items back with the model instance: 
    @Html.EditorFor(c => item, "MyEditorTemplate") 
}
```

For a detailed answer why this is, look at this question: [MVC can't override EditorTemplate name when used in EditorFor for child object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629763/mvc-cant-override-editortemplate-name-when-used-in-editorfor-for-child-object).