# How to concatenate a string to the data returned by the model in MVC4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, string, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am very new to .NET and am using MVC 4. I have a variable "AvgAnnualGrowth" of type double. This variable can have positive or negative values. When it is negative, I should display "-" before the data and when its positive, I should display "+" before the data. There is no problem with the negative data as the double variable displays "-" by default. For positive values, it does not display "+" explicitly. Any ideas on how to concatenate "+" in front of the data?

Following is the code snippet from my (view) cshtml file.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <tr>                
        <td align="right">                    
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AvgAnnualGrowth)
        </td>   
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Piece together the code from the question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724295/ienumerable-in-my-viewmodel-is-not-displayed-with-editorformodel.  Basically, you'll create a Razor file for your `double` where you will prepend a `+` to the value of the input field if the `double` passed in is positive.  Then instead of using `.DisplayFor`, you'll use `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.AvgAnnualGrowth, "NameOfDoubleTemplate")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could label just before the DisplayFor

```
@Html.Label(item.AvgAnnualGrowth > 0 ? "+" : "")@Html.Display...
```

Comment: @JoelMuthurajJohn that's good. if it was helpful and the answer then it's customary to upvote my answer and accept it as the answer.  I see you're new so I understand there's a lot to pickup.

Comment: Thanks dove. I have accepted it as answer but cant upvote it as I dont have enough reputation.

Comment: @JoelMuthurajJohn thanks, you should have enough reputation to vote now ;)